# One or more certificates rejected. Cannot proceed with installation

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

when build wso2 am, on ubuntu 16.04, with  git checkout product-apim,
and run

```
 mvn clean install
```

and failed, said that certificates rejected, but don't which one is rejected.

the output like this:

```
Installing carbon.product.id 4.4.2.
Installation failed.
One or more certificates rejected. Cannot proceed with installation.
Application failed, log file location: /home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/tycho/tycho-p2-runtime/0.13.0/eclipse/configuration/1465283477879.log

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Aggregator Module ............... SUCCESS [  0.678 s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Styles Parent ................... SUCCESS [  0.068 s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Styles .......................... SUCCESS [  1.877 s]
[INFO] WSO2 Stratos  API Manager - UI styles .............. SUCCESS [  3.018 s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Multi Tenant Dashboard .......... SUCCESS [  1.414 s]
[INFO] WSO2 Stratos  API Manager - Dashboard UI ........... SUCCESS [  1.571 s]
[INFO] WSO2 AM - Login User Interface ..................... SUCCESS [  1.325 s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Features Parent ................. SUCCESS [  0.031 s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Features Aggregator Module ...... SUCCESS [  0.024 s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Styles Features ................. SUCCESS [  0.473 s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - Multi Tenant Dashboard Feature .. SUCCESS [  1.877 s]
[INFO] WSO2 Stratos  API Manager - Features Aggregator Module SUCCESS [  0.025 s]
[INFO] WSO2 Stratos  API Manager - Style Features ......... SUCCESS [  0.678 s]
[INFO] WSO2 Stratos  API Manager - Utils Features ......... SUCCESS [  0.901 s]
[INFO] WSO2 Stratos  API Manager - Dashboard UI Features .. SUCCESS [  0.758 s]
[INFO] WSO2 Stratos  API Manager - Deployment Features .... SUCCESS [  0.652 s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - P2 Profile Generation Parent .... SUCCESS [  0.053 s]
[INFO] WSO2 API Manager - P2 Profile Generation ........... FAILURE [ 40.276 s]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

any hints? thanks!

Comment: Which branch you have built? Also, add the relavent log portion here.

Comment: HEAD detached at v1.10.0.

Comment: log file content:  !SESSION 2016-06-07 07:11:17.740 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_91
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US

Comment: Framework arguments:  -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -metadataRepository file:/home/ubuntu/workspace/product-apim/modules/p2-profile/product/target/p2-repo -artifactRepository file:/home/ubuntu/workspace/product-apim/modules/p2-profile/product/target/p2-repo -installIU carbon.product.id

Comment: -profileProperties org.eclipse.update.install.features=true -profile gateway-manager -bundlepool file:/home/ubuntu/workspace/product-apim/modules/p2-profile/product/target/wso2carbon-core-4.4.3/repository/components -shared file:/home/ubuntu/workspace/product-apim/modules/p2-profile/product/target/wso2carbon-core-4.4.3/repository/components/p2 -destination file:/home/ubuntu/workspace/product-apim/modules/p2-profile/product/target/wso2carbon-core-4.4.3/repository/components/gateway-manager -p2.os linux -p2.ws gtk -p2.arch x86 -roaming

Comment: Command-line arguments:  -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -metadataRepository file:/home/ubuntu/workspace/product-apim/modules/p2-profile/product/target/p2-repo -artifactRepository file:/home/ubuntu/workspace/product-apim/modules/p2-profile/product/target/p2-repo -installIU carbon.product.id -profileProperties org.eclipse.update.install.features=true

Comment: -profile gateway-manager -bundlepool file:/home/ubuntu/workspace/product-apim/modules/p2-profile/product/target/wso2carbon-core-4.4.3/repository/components -shared file:/home/ubuntu/workspace/product-apim/modules/p2-profile/product/target/wso2carbon-core-4.4.3/repository/components/p2 -destination file:/home/ubuntu/workspace/product-apim/modules/p2-profile/product/target/wso2carbon-core-4.4.3/repository/components/gateway-manager -p2.os linux -p2.ws gtk -p2.arch x86 -roaming

Comment: !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 8 0 2016-06-07 07:11:20.220
!MESSAGE One or more certificates rejected. Cannot proceed with installation.